# "Propose Tag Wiki" button doesn't appear after error on submit!

Tags: support, tag-wiki

About two days ago, I was editing a tag wiki.
When submitting, an error appeared, but dumb-ass-me, I didn't pay attention and just pressed the available button.

Was something about an error that had occurred, but that I shouldn't worry because it had been logged and someone was going to deal with it.

Anyway, since then I can't propose any tag-wiki suggestion. Seems like the <kbd>Propose Tag Wiki</kbd> is hidden for my user.

Can someone enlighten me on this subject?

**Ps:**
The <kbd>Edit Tag Wiki</kbd> also doesn't appear.

[image: missing buttons print-screen]

Comment: Your edits haven't been reviewed yet, I guess this feature is to prevent a new tag wiki editor from filling up the edit queue before they've gotten feedback. I'll review them now.

Comment: I think it may possibly be due to rejected suggestions in this case, because the queue is clear (has been most of the day). Either that or his suggestions got lost in the ether somewhere.

Comment: On the day that the error appeared, I had some suggestions approved! one after the other, etc. Is there a way for me to view my suggested edits that have been rejected?

Comment: @Zuul: I don't think there's a way to list your suggestions based on their outcome, but if you go into [your suggestions activity](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/16265/zuul?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and just pick one it'll give you a summary at the bottom. Your stats show 13 approved and 9 rejected total.

Comment: Lol my bad, I missed the "two days ago" thing.  Thanks @eldarerathis, I agree it's likely due to too many rejections.

Comment: Damn, and there I was believing that they were productive edits  :)

Comment: So, if I'm not mistaken, one week is the penalty, yes?

Comment: Currently, the only way to see your rejected edits is to go into your "Activity" tab and open each of your suggested edits. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lack of buttons to allow edits on tag wikis as well on questions happens when a user reaches a limit set for rejected suggested edits.

Detailed information can be found at:

[FAQ - How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/184576)

> There are strict limits enforced. If a user (anonymous or registered) submits many rejected edits they will be automatically banned from suggesting edits for 7 days. The fixed size queue also helps protect us from abuse.

This is explained by [Jeff Atwood♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78192/184576) answer to the question:

[Is there a penalty for one's edit suggestion being rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78129/184576)

> No, but repeated edit suggestion rejections from multiple users will cause your edit suggestion rights to be suspended for (n) days, where n is currently 7.